# How to solve this problem using Particle Swarm Optimization?

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization

I'm currently revising my optimization algorithm for a specific part of a problem. I have trouble in wrapping my head around a new approach and my mind is having this tunnel-vision of ideas. I could really use some fresh perspectives.

I'll try my best to simply the explanation.

(Please see attached file "Example-1.png" and "Example-2.png")

---

Say, we are given 3 distinct persons.

Each of these person have a specific **Supply** (an item that he/she possess) and a **Need** (an item that needs to be acquired). Now, if these **Supply-Need** is reversed, and their reverse can be found in another person, they can be traded.

Moreover, the pairs have a numerical value called **Gravity** that specifies the importance of the pair to the person. We can treat it as a *weight* on how much a person can be "*satisfied*" if the **Supply-Need** pair is met. Each person can only allocate and distribute 100-points of **Gravity** among all of his/her **Supply-Need** pairs.

Now, the **Total Satisfaction** of this process can be computed by getting the sum of all the Persons' individual satisfactions.

The objective is to have the group of Persons trade their **Supply-Need** pair/s in different combinations such that we can acquire the largest **Total Satisfaction** as possible.

---

In PSO, each *Particle* represents a candidate solution based on its location in the Search Space.

Given the attached examples in this post, we can say that *Example-1.PNG* is a distinct candidate solution to this problem, as well as *Example-2.PNG*.

---

What's the best approach in how this problem can be represented and evaluated by a Fitness/Objective Function?

How would you characterize this problem in PSO?

Do you have any recommendations of published work with the same problem as this?

Cheers!

**EXAMPLE-1.PNG**

### [image: Example-1.png]

**EXAMPLE-2.PNG**
[image: Example-2.png]

Comment: I guess I'm confused by your problem. Can you express it mathematically as some sort of nonlinear program? Why do you need to use PSO?

Comment: I'm trying have PSO to treat my problem as a black box, given its meta-heuristic nature . Also, I need PSO since it provides fair solutions (not necessarily the optimum) in just a short span of time.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a dynamic programming approach would fit as it it seems to be close to the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

If you go for the PSO, I think you could express the quantity each person gets from a particular supply as a variable to your problem. Then you'll have to express your constraints and your objective function. You should have an [ILP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming)

After that you could use the PSO algorithm to search for good solutions. Here is a paper found from google scholar (is seems to be cited many many times)

www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/wcci/2002/7282/02/01004478.pdf